Generating paths - tsconfig.base.json
When I run the following command:
nx generate @nx/angular:library libs/navigation/feature/tabs

I get the following entry in tsconfig.base.json:
"@app/tabs": ["libs/navigation/feature/tabs/src/index.ts"],

However, I expected the result to be:
"@app/navigation/feature/tabs": ["libs/navigation/feature/tabs/src/index.ts"],

How  can I achieve this expected result without having to modify it manually?

Depending on whether you are using the workspace generator, the default configuration could be either in nx.json file or in workspace generator configuration. In order to achieve the indented result, please modify the configuration files or use importPath property along with cli command:
nx generate @nx/angular:library libs/navigation/feature/tabs --importPath=@app/navigation/feature/tabs


Your answer is good, i'm understand now :)
